# How to do repeated API calls to another server, with a threshold timer (in order to give up)?

Tags: api, cron

I am looking for a good way to implement a module which will repeatedly call an API web service for about an hour let's say, after which it needs to break and log an error to a file. I know that I can use a cron job in Magento, so which do you recommend? Thanks!